# Making a nested dictionaries from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

### PROBLEM STATEMENT

x is an input list of dictionaries  which needs to be formatted to y which is also a list of dictionaries  , but in this case the key is pickupAddress and the sub dictionary  consist of { zipcode,lat,long}

so basically , i want to transform x to y

### Approach taken

1. have used tuples to store the values and then inserted to a list

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeBdL.png)

```html
deliveryAddress={}
pickupAddress={}
l1=[]
l2=[]
l1_del=[]
l2_pick=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
    k1=('zipcode',x[i]['delivery_zip'])
    l1.append(k1)
    k2=('longitude',x[i]['delivery_lng'])
    l1.append(k2)
    k3=('latitude',x[i]['delivery_lat'])
    l1.append(k3)
    
    k4=('zipcode',x[i]['latitude'])
    l2.append(k4)
    k5=('longitude',x[i]['longitude'])
    l2.append(k5)
    k6=('latitude',x[i]['zipcode'])
    l2.append(k6)
    
    t1=("pickupAddress",l1)
    t2=("deliveryAddress",l2)
    
    print(l1)
    print(l2)
    if i < len(x):
        print(len(x))
        l1_del.append(t1)
        l2_pick.append(t2)
        del l1
        del l2 
        
        l1=[]
        l2=[]
```

### INPUT

[LIST_OF_DICTIONARY INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm064.png)

### CODE SNIPET

```html
[{'delivery_zip': '12432',
  'delivery_lat': 42.0437,
  'delivery_lng': -73.9474,
  'distance': 43.81927669168279,
  'latitude': 41.6770047,
  'longitude': -73.7535413,
  'zipcode': 12510},
 {'delivery_zip': '12404',
  'delivery_lat': 41.8293989,
  'delivery_lng': -74.2414092,
  'distance': 43.872670571109516,
  'latitude': 41.6770047,
  'longitude': -73.7535413,
  'zipcode': 12510}]
```

### OUTPUT

[OUTPUT_FORMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKCl7.png)

```html
y=[{
    "pickupAddress": { "zipcode": "12510", "latitude": 41.6770047, "longitude": -73.7535413 }, 
    "deliveryAddress": { "zipcode": "12432", "latitude": 42.0437, "longitude": -73.9474 }
  },
    {
     "pickupAddress": { "zipcode": "12510", "latitude": 41.6770047, "longitude": -73.7535413 },  
    "deliveryAddress": { "zipcode": "12404", "latitude": 41.8293989, "longitude": -74.2414092 }
  }

]
```

[output approach1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYXpP.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as [no effort](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) or [code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) whatsoever has been provided as part of this question. Please note that SO is **not** a free coding service.

Comment: OK, so you've created the two sub-dicts.  Now, you just need to combine them into a single combined dict, and add that dict to a master list.

Comment: yes that's what i thought , but at every iteration the new elements  going to come

Comment: @rv.kvetch , i have added the approaches you can review it .

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, as the question looks fair to me now. I'd also add the code in the image as text, in case it's relevant to the question, that way it should be easier for others to reproduce or run it if needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**. When I read this, I have absolutely no idea what you want to do. I can't tell which parts of the post are supposed to be example input, desired output or actual output.

Comment: thanks @rv.kvetch and karl can you look the post , i have clarified everything let me know if you need more clarification .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform one list into another list, use a list comprehension:

```
y = [
        {
            "pickupAddress": { "zipcode": obj['zipcode'], "latitude": obj['latitude'], "longitude": obj['longitude']},
            "deliveryAddress": {"zipcode": obj['delivery_zip'], "latitude": obj['delivery_lat'], "longitude": obj['delivery_lng'] }
        }
        for obj in x
    ]
```